# How do I create the Windows Equivalent of This Very Small Shell Script?

Tags: shell, batch-file, terminal, command-prompt

I'm trying to achieve the following but in a `.bat` file. It executes all arguments after the first one, after having set the path.

```
# Add your local node_modules bin to the path for this command
export PATH="./node_modules/.bin:$PATH"

# execute the rest of the command
exec "$@"
```

I've got the first part (I think) but don't know how to do the second part, and have not been successful in Googling the solution.

```
REM Add your local node_modules bin to the path for this command
SET PATH=.\node_modules\.bin;%PATH%
```

Comment: I would recommend that you do not add relative paths to `%PATH%`; use `%CD%` instead of `.`.

Comment: https://batsh.org may help you figure it out. Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first command line could be:

```
@set "PATH=%~dp0node_modules\.bin;%PATH%"
```

This command line adds to **local** `PATH` environment variable at beginning the path of subdirectory `.bin` in subdirectory `node_modules` in **directory of the batch file** instead of the *current directory*.

`%~dp0` expands always to the batch file directory path ending with a backslash. For that reason `%~dp0` should be always concatenated with a folder/file name without an additional backslash as done here.

It would be possible to use `%CD%\` instead of `%~dp0` to add the path of subdirectory `.bin` in subdirectory `node_modules` in the *current directory* to **local** `PATH` environment variable. But please be aware that *current directory* can be always different to **batch file directory** and is for that reason most likely not good here.

`%CD%` expands to a directory path string not ending with a backslash, except the *current directory* is the root directory of a drive in which case `%CD%` expands to drive letter + colon + backslash. Therefore the usage of `%CD%` would require the command line:

```
@if not "%CD:~-1%" == "\" (set "PATH=%CD%\node_modules\.bin;%PATH%") else set "PATH=%CD%node_modules\.bin;%PATH%"
```

The second command line could be:

```
@%*
```

That very short command line results in getting interpreted all arguments passed to the batch file with exception of argument 0 as command line to execute by Windows command processor after parsing it. See also: [How does the Windows Command Interpreter (CMD.EXE) parse scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4094699/)

`@` at beginning of a command line results in Windows command processor `cmd.exe` processing the batch file does not output the command line after parsing it. The command line with command `set` and with `%*` do not need anymore `@` at beginning of the line with `@echo off` at top of the batch file.

```
@echo off
set "PATH=%~dp0node_modules\.bin;%PATH%"
%*
```

Open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/10-ways-to-open-the-command-prompt-in-windows-10/), run `call /?` and read the output help explaining how batch file arguments can be referenced in a batch file.

See also [SS64.com](https://ss64.com/) which has a reference for Windows CMD and Linux Shell commands.